# Кодирование словаря

Tags: python

Метод `users.get(user_ids=364960638)` вернул мне такую строку.

```py
[{u'first_name': u'\u0410\u043d\u0442\u043e\u043d', u'last_name': u'\u0421\u0442\u044f\u0436\u043a\u0438\u043d', u'id': 364960638}]
```

Как можно перевести ее на русский? Не знаю как применить метод

```py
.encode('utf-8')
```

Comment: @m0nhawk, я пытался, но AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'encode', чего-то я не понмаю

Comment: @m0nhawk, я выводил. Результат вывода в вопросе.

Comment: Это не строка, а список, содержащий в себе словарь. А строки в этом словаре вполне себе русские, просто при печати списка неанглийские буквы экранируются. Если вы хотите просто работать с этими строками дальше (записать в файл, например) — ничего делать не надо, они и так русские. Если вы хотите красиво их отпечатать в консоль — расскажите, как и зачем.

Comment: @andreymal, я просто хочу вывести в терминал имя и фамилию. Что-то вроде

`user_data={}
api = vk_requests.create_api(app_id='id', login='login', password='password')
user_data = api.users.get(user_ids=364960638)
print user_data['first_name']`

Если я правильно понял словари эти, то они работают именно так. Но дело в том, что в консоли выводятся набор байтов (не уверен). А мне нужна строка на русском.

Comment: Ещё раз, это не словарь, а список содержащий словарь :) Имя должно отпечататься нормально с помощью `print(user_data[0]['first_name'])`

Comment: @andreymal, ааа, что-то я сглупил сильно :))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В питоне есть такая функция — `repr`. Её назначение — вернуть строку, в которой будет представлен переданный её объект по возможности в такой форме, которую можно будет распарсить как Python-код и таким образом восстановить объект. (То есть, например, `repr([3, 4, 5])` даст строку `'[3, 4, 5]'`, содержимое которой является корректным кодом Python, при выполнении которого получится такой же список).

Так вот, в Python 2 особенность в том, что для unicode-строк (для байтовых, впрочем, тоже) все неанглийские символы экранируются:

```
>>> print repr(u'Вася')
u'\u0412\u0430\u0441\u044f'
```

Ещё раз замечу, что это корректный Python-код, а именно unicode-строка, и если мы попытаемся её отпечатать, то получим нормальные русские буквы:

```
>>> print u'\u0412\u0430\u0441\u044f'
Вася
```

А строки с экранированными и неэкранированными символами являются абсолютно одинаковыми, это они просто записаны в немного разном виде:

```
>>> u'Вася' == u'\u0412\u0430\u0441\u044f'
True
>>> u'Вася' == u'Ва\u0441я'
True
>>> print u'\u0412\u0430\u0441\u044f'[3]  # Печатаем четвёртый симвлол строки
я
```

Так вот [2], при печати словаря (и многих других объектов, кроме строк) как раз вызывается эта самая функция `repr`, и для всего содержимого словаря тоже вызывается `repr`, чтобы получился корректный Python-код:

```
>>> print repr({"name": u"Вася"})
{'name': u'\u0412\u0430\u0441\u044f'}
>>> print {"name": u"Вася"}
{'name': u'\u0412\u0430\u0441\u044f'}
```

И чтобы отпечатать русскую строку, достаточно лишь вытащить её из словаря и отпечатать одну лишь её:

```
>>> user_data = api.users.get(user_ids=364960638)[0]
>>> print user_data['first_name']
Антон
>>> print repr(user_data['first_name'])
u'\u0410\u043d\u0442\u043e\u043d'
```

Отмечу, что в Python 3 `repr` ничего не экранирует и печатает нормально, так что настоятельно рекомендую переходить на него :)

<sub>P.S. Для зануд: сложные объекты не всегда легко представимы в виде адекватного Python-кода, так что для них `repr` может вернуть не Python-код и полагаться на него стоит не всегда: например, `repr(repr)` => `'<built-in function repr>'`</sub>